# FullCalendar: all day slot not showing up in agendaDay view

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar in my MVC app. It's working great except for one annoying little thing. The all day slot won't show up on agendaDay view. It shows up fine in the agendaWeek but not for agendaDay. I checked it in Firebug and the tr for all day slot is not being rendered. This app is using a lot of .js files (none of which I've written) and the file that manipulates the calendar has the following code in the .fullcalendar call (among other things):

```
            eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                if (!event.sphere) {
                    element.removeClass("fc-event");
                    element.addClass("fc-event-business");
                }

                if (typeof (currentItem) !== 'undefined' && currentItem != null && typeof (currentEvents) !== 'undefined' && currentEvents != null) {

                    if (typeof (eventsAmount) == 'undefined' || eventsAmount == null) {
                        eventsAmount = 0;
                    }

                    currentItem++;
                    if (currentItem == 1) {

                        for (keyevent in currentEvents) {
                            if (new Date(currentEvents[keyevent].start) >= view.visStart && new Date(currentEvents[keyevent].end) <= view.visEnd) {
                                eventsAmount++;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    if (currentItem == 1 || currentItem == eventsAmount) {

                        MyJS.SetContentHeight(false);
                        if (currentItem == eventsAmount) {
                            currentItem = 0;
                            eventsAmount = 0;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    MyJS.SetContentHeight(false);
                }
            },
```

Could this be the reason why all day slot is not being rendered? How should I change this in order to show the slot? I have limited knowledge of JavaScript and jQuery, so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this function has no effect what so ever. Tried removing it and it still won't show. Come to think of it firstHour doesn't work either. My calendar is showing from midnight instead of from 6 am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. There was a call to hide the element with a specified class somewhere deep in the code. It hid the header for agendaDay. 
But firstHour still doesn't work. BTW it's fullcalendar 1.4.5.